# How can I concat current date with title in shell script?

Tags: excel, shell, testing, automated-tests

I am working on shellscript with excel sheet. Till now I have done as shown in screenshot by using below command:

```
bash execution.sh BehatIPOP.xls| awk '/Script|scenario/' | awk 'BEGIN{print "Title\tResult"}1' | awk '0 == NR%2{printf "%s",$0;next;}1' >> BehatIPOP.xls
```

[image]

My requirement is along with the heading Result I want to add(concat) current date also. So I am getting date by using below command:

```
$(date +"%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

So date will display like this : `25-08-2016 17:00:00`

But I am not getting how can use date command in the above mentioned command to achieve heading like below:

```
 |      Title       |   Result @ 25-08-2016 17:00:00|
```

Thanks for any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up the date inside `awk` and store it in a variable `d` like this, if that is what you mean:

```
awk 'BEGIN{cmd="date +\"%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S\""; cmd |getline d; close(cmd);print "Result @ " d}'
Result @ 25-08-16 13:44:05
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use awk at all for the header, just use `date` directly:

```
{ printf "Title\tResult @ "; date +"%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"; bash execution.sh BehatIPOP.xls | 
    awk '/Script|scenario/' | 
    awk '1 == NR%2{printf "%s",$0;next;}1'; } >> BehatIPOP.xls
```

Note that there's no need for 2 awks, but I'm keeping that here to minimize the diff.  Since I've pulled the header out of the awk, the comparison changes from `0==NR%2` to `1==NR%2`.